# Disable secure-file-priv on Debian

Tags: debian, mysql, debian-jessie

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.3
```

I'm trying to do a INTO OUTFILE and I get getting an error saying --secure-file-priv is enabled.

I've tried adding secure-file-priv = "" and secure_file_priv = "" to /etc/mysql/my.cnf and nothing seems to work.